# check doubles content array in localstorage javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

how to check the contents of the array of doubles , if there is an array of [ 1,2,2,3,1 ] so the value you 've entered will not be entered again ?

```js
function cek() {
    resi_or_code = document.getElementById('code_or_resi').value;
    resi = resi_or_code.split(',');

    if($.trim(resi_or_code) != ''){
        //location.href = base_url + 'resi/' + encodeURIComponent(resi_or_code);
    }
    if (localStorage.daftar_data){
        daftar_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('daftar_data'));
        $("#riwayat").toggle();
    } else {
        daftar_data = [];
    }
       
    for (x in resi){
        console.log(localStorage.daftar_data);
        daftar_data.push({'resis':resi[x]});
        localStorage.setItem('daftar_data', JSON.stringify(daftar_data));
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: [Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
resis
:
"030023706726"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array[0]

Comment: if your are using any utils libraries like lodash look into https://lodash.com/docs#uniq

use combinations _.merge and _.uniq or _.uniqBy to get a solution. 
i didn't get your question clearly so i'm not able to provide a complete solution which can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
for (x in resi){
  console.log(localStorage.daftar_data);
  if(!daftar_data.includes(resi[x])){ 
      daftar_data.push({'resis':resi[x]}); 
  }
}
localStorage.setItem('daftar_data', JSON.stringify(daftar_data));
```

Comment: I love ES6 but if IE support is required [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) could be an efficient alternative until Microsoft eventually gets its act together.

Comment: comparing data localstrorage denagn input data

Answer (score 0):

you can use the indexOf also i.e. [Array.prototype.indexOf(el)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) where el is the element.indexOf method returns the index of the element in the array, if it is not present then it returns -1.

```
for (x in resi){
   if(daftar_data.indexOf(resi[x]) > -1) {
      daftar_data.push({'resis':resi[x]});
   }
}
localStorage.setItem('daftar_data', JSON.stringify(daftar_data));
```

Comment: for (y in daftar_data){
        var q =  daftar_data[y].resis;
        for (x in resi){
        console.log(q); 
            if (q === resi[x]) 
            {   
            console.log('Value exist');

            }else{
            console.log('Value does not exist');
            daftar_data.push({'resis':resi[x]});
            localStorage.setItem('daftar_data', JSON.stringify(daftar_data));
            } 
        }
    }

Comment: comparing data localstrorage denagn input data

Comment: @Iswadi Can you please explain what you want to say. I think you put your code in wrong box.